# IE8 text-overflow without fixed width

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have a problem in IE8 when using text-overflow and overflow hidden. Although IE8 correctly trims the text and hides its overflow from the view, the span with the truncated text still blows out the width on the parent element.

Using a fixed width on either the span or its parent element works fine but unfortunately I can not use a fixed width. I have tried using a width:100% and max-width on the truncating span element as well as putting a max-width on the parent element with no luck in IE8.

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/cmoeser/aRvXg/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">

.containerDiv {
    float:right;
    border:1px solid green;
    overflow:hidden!important;
    zoom:1;
}
.textDiv {
     float:left;
     zoom:1;
     white-space: nowrap;
     display:block;
     max-width:128px;
     overflow:hidden;
     -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
     text-overflow:ellipsis;   
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="containerDiv">
        <span class="textDiv">WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

what if you try

```
 .textdiv {float:right; text-align:left;}
```

can't use js fiddle on ie8

Comment: Thanks. Floating in either direction or text-align have no effect.

Comment: try using max-width on parent and then using width:auto

Comment: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/ie8-bug-max-width-overflow
sounds similar to your bug may help

Comment: Yup, exact same problem. Setting a max-width keeps the parent element from ever getting bigger than desired but the parent never collapses to the truncated width of the inner element.